# Is ANSI C / ISO C++ supported in all mobile operating systems?

Tags: c++, c, mobile, operating-system

I want to develope a library with **ANSI C**, and another library with **ISO C++**.

I don't use any additional libraries. All lines of my code is pure ANSI C (89) / ISO C++ (2003).

Note that in my own C++ library, I use C++ exceptions and also I use STL.

Is These languages fully supported in most importand mobile operating systems likes **Windows Mobile**, **BlackBerry OS**, **Symbian** and **Android**?

Honestly I know the answer for **Windows Mobile** is **YES**. But I dont sure for other OSes.

Comment: To be brutally honest, a few minutes googling will tell you the answer for all OS'es you mentioned.

Comment: You should ask two separate questions, one for C and one for C++.

Comment: @Perception: I said "most importand mobile operating systems", may be there is a better mobile operating systems, and I dont know.

Comment: Totally as an aside, ANSI C is C99.  C89 was replaced 12 years ago, it's long since time to modernize.

Comment: You did say 'most important mobile operating systems' correct?  I'm asking because you skipped the iPhone.

Comment: @Amir - the short answer to your question is no. Ansi C/ISO C++ is not ***fully*** supported on all mobile phone operating systems, and definitely not on all the ones you mentioned above. You will find it easiest to integrate a *pure* C/C++ library into iPhone and Symbian. The rest ... meh.

Answer (score 3):

No. Windows Phone 7 supports only managed applications. It does not allow you to write apps in C++ or link with C++ libraries.

Comment: This really sounds wrong - how can you create a program and use no external libraries?  (Note, this doesn't mean .dll's or .so's or anything like that, just a .lib that you link with - it could even be a .o)

Comment: It means I cant write a standard C/C++ application?

Comment: @Amir - that's another, separate question.

Comment: It does sound wrong, doesn't it? There was not even a database available at first.

Comment: What your answer says though is that it's not possible to link with previously created objects.  As an extension of that answer, it would mean you couldn't have two source files. Additionally, the OP states that he knows that the answer for Win Mobile is yes.

Comment: You can have as many managed-language source files as you want and link with managed DLLs.

Comment: @Don - So, if you have a collection of functions that you use for your domain, you can't statically link them with your application? (Even if they are linked as .obj's?)

Comment: You got it. Have to rewrite them in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Symbian uses standard c++ and Qt

Android is programmed in Java (or a language identical to Java but not Java depending on how the Oracle lawsuit turns out!) you can use the Native dev kit to load C libraries.

Blackberry is QNX based and uses c++

Comment: The native dev kit can run C++ as well. All you need is a simple C JNI wrapper.

Comment: @Ethan - but you can't write full c++ apps, right? The app (and gui) is still in Java

Comment: GUI's aren't standard C++ anyway. Don't know about `<iostream>`on Android.